# iPhone dev: UIBarButtonItem or title not showing up in NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

here my problem. I have a NavigationBar at the top, a TabBar at the bottom and a TableView at the center of the screen. Very normal situation. I set it all up in IB and I have set this in the app delegate :

ExpensesListNavController *expensesListNavController;

This in order to be able to add new views to the stack. I need to have 3 levels:
- list of items in a TableView -> OK
- firstLevel: once pressed one cell a view is added to the stack -> OK
- second level: one pressed the "modify" button on the navBar on the firstLevel I want to show a new view that can be customized by the user.

My Problem is coming when trying to add the "Modify" button in the "firstLevelView". Here-below my code

```
-(IBAction) modify:(id)sender
{
 if (editableDetailViewController == nil) 
 {
  editableDetailViewController = [[editableDetailViewController alloc] init];
 }
 editableDetailViewController.expense = expense;

 [appDelegate.expensesListNavController pushViewController:editableDetailViewController animated:YES];
 editableDetailViewController = nil;
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 UIBarButtonItem *modifyButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Modify" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(modify:)];
 appDelegate.expensesListNavController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = modifyButton;
 appDelegate.expensesListNavController.navigationItem.title = @"Titoloooo";
 NSLog(@"NavBar button has just been set !!");
 [modifyButton release];
```

Nothing is being showed, neither title nor the button. Do you have any idea of what is happening ?? I really cannot figure out !!!

Thanks a lot in advance, AM

Comment: Please help us out!  Please use the {} button on the edit box to put your code in a more readable format :)

Comment: You could mark your question as solved once it is. Or give feedback to the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well - I'm far from being an expert here - but the code you're showing is from your "firstLevel" class? Or do you instantiate your classes in advance and switch views manually?

In Interface Builder, set up MainWindow (generated automatically on project setup)
Well, I'd prepared a screenshot from my Interface BUilder setup. Seems I'm missing reputation to be able to post it.

Basically,  you'll add to MainWindow.xib a Navigation Controller,

- to it, you add a navigation bar.
- Move the Root View Controller under the navigation Controller.
- add a UINavigationItem to the Root View Controller
- add a UIBarButtonItem to the UINavigationItem
- connect the outlet of the UIBarButtonItem to your IBAction

  In the corresponding viewcontroller class, you'll need your "modify" method.

  ```
  // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
  -(IBAction)modify:(id)sender {
      controller = [[firstLevel alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondLevel" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
      [controller release];
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The code I posted, even if I wasn't sufficiently clear, is coming from the "first level". The thing is that, since I want the "second level" to be instantiated from the first (once the modify button is pressed) I need to create that button first... And here my issue ! Cannot figure out how to create it ! The ExpensesListNavController is simply a class derived form UINavigationController, with nothing at its inside !!

Comment: ok. Updated the solution again - that's basically my working setup.